# Expression for stopband deviation of a digital filter

Tags: digital-filters

Beginning from the basic definition of decibel that expresses the ratio of two amplitudes as $20\log_{10}(A_{2}/A_{1}) $, how do we arrive at the expression $-20\log_{10}(\delta_{s})$ measured in dB, for the stopband deviation of a digital filter?

[image]

Comment: Well, your question “how do we arrive” assumes we “started” somewhere. So, please edit your question to give us more context: where did you start, and what is the actual question? Why do we use $20\log_{10}$? Or how to get to stopband_attenuation? Or something else?

Comment: @Jdip Please refer to my edited question. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Please, define $\delta_s$.

Comment: @MBaz It's stopband deviation as shown in the figure attached.

Comment: Are you sure you meant stop band *attenuation*? $\delta_s$ usually symbolizes stop band *ripple*

Comment: @Jdip Apologies! I meant stopband deviation.

Comment: Why don't you just accept the definitions presented by the textbook from which this figure was taken from?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson After all, it must have some justification.

Comment: It's a label.  "$\delta_s$" is the label which we give to the maximum allowed gain in the stopband.  That is the maximum deviation (in linear amplitude, ***not*** dB) of the stopband gain is from its target gain of $0$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You are spot on!. However, the expressions you have included in your answer do not match with the expressions for passband and stopband ripples (expressed in dB) in the literature.

Comment: I used the definition of the dB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stop band ripple, $\delta_s$ is measured with respect to the pass band amplitude (usually 1).

That means:

$$
20 \log_{10}\left (\frac{\delta_s }{ 1 } \right) = 20 \log_{10}\left (\delta_s \right)
$$

but this is the stop band **gain** and most people think about the stop band in terms of **attenuation**.  So it's more usual to have:

$$
-20 \log_{10}\left (\delta_s \right)
$$
Because, for a good filter, $\delta_s \ll 1$, $\log_{10}(\delta_s)$ is negative, so the minus sign just makes the number positive (and an attenuation rather than a gain).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just confused about the reference amplitude for calculation of stopband deviation in dB. I was taking 0 as reference and that caused the whole confusion.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_s$ is the maximum amplitude in the stopband RELATIVE to the nominal amplitude in the passband, $A_{pass}$ . For any standard filter design the latter is 1, i.e. $A_{pass} = 1$. Converting the ratio to dB we get the stop band attenuation as

$$A_{stop} = 20 \cdot \log_{10}\frac{A_{pass}}{\delta_s} = 20 \cdot \log_{10}\frac{1}{\delta_s} = -20 \cdot \log_{10}\delta_s$$

Comment: It's pretty clear from the figure included in the question that the target passband gain is 1 (or 0 dB).  And that the target stopband gain is 0 (or $-\infty$ dB).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just confused about the reference amplitude for calculation of stopband deviation in dB. I was taking 0 as reference and that caused the whole confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The target gain for the stopband is $0$ or $-\infty$ dB.  That is also the minimum amplitude of the stopband.  The maximum amplitude of the stopband is $\delta_s$ (the deviation from $0$) or $20 \log_{10}(\delta_s)$ dB.

The target gain of the passband is $1$ or $0$ dB.  The maximum gain of the passband is $1+\delta_p$ and the minimum passband gain is $1-\delta_p$, where $\delta_p$ is the deviation from $1$.  In dB, the passband ripple is

$$20\log_{10}\left(\frac{1+\delta_p}{1-\delta_p} \right)$$

If this deviation is small, $\delta_p \ll 1$, then this passband ripple is approximated as

$$\begin{align}
20\log_{10}\left(\frac{1+\delta_p}{1-\delta_p} \right) &= 20\log_{10}(1+\delta_p) - 20\log_{10}(1-\delta_p) \\
\\
 &= \frac{20}{\ln(10)}\ln(1+\delta_p) - \frac{20}{\ln(10)}\ln(1-\delta_p) \\
\\
 &\approx \frac{20}{\ln(10)}(\delta_p) - \frac{20}{\ln(10)}(-\delta_p) \\
\\ 
 &= \frac{40 \ \delta_p}{\ln(10)} \qquad \qquad \text{dB} \\
\end{align} $$

Comment: What about $\delta_s$?

Comment: $20 \log_{10}(\delta_s)$ is the maximum gain of the stopband in dB.